# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in line 960

Tags: php, html, wordpress, syntax-error

It's for a Wordpress site - I was messing around with some sidebar stuff and this happened. Line 960 looks this currently, by the way:

```
   'id' => 'main-sidebar',
```

I realize that the parse error is telling me that the double arrow is wrong/unexpected, but I don't know what should be there instead. The whole block looks like this:

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Main Sidebar', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'main-sidebar',
    'description' => __('The main sidebar area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like an idiot.

EDIT: Here's more of the code (this is the whole sidebar area):

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Main Sidebar', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'main-sidebar',
    'description' => __('The main sidebar area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Shop Sidebar', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'shop-sidebar',
    'description' => __('Shop page widget area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Single product page Sidebar', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'single-sidebar',
    'description' => __('Single product page widget area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Shopping cart sidebar', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'cart-sidebar',
    'description' => __('Area after cart totals block', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Right side panel area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'right-panel-sidebar',
    'description' => __('Right side panel widget area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Hidden top panel area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'top-panel-sidebar',
    'description' => __('Hidden top panel widget area', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Place in header top bar', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'languages-sidebar',
    'description' => __('Can be used for placing languages switcher of some contacts information.', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Prefooter Row', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'prefooter',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="prefooter-sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //prefooter-sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));


register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer 1', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'footer1',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="footer-sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //footer-sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer 2', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'footer2',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="footer-sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));


register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer Copyright', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'footer9',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="footer-sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //footer-sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer Links', ETHEME_DOMAIN),
    'id' => 'footer10',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="footer-sidebar-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><!-- //footer-sidebar-widget -->',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));

}
```

EDIT 2: Here's the line to the entire code file since someone asked for it: http://pastebin.com/SUnh0Ft8
Pretty sure ETHEME_DOMAIN is just the php redirect to the site's domain. Could be wrong though.

Comment: What is `ETHEME_DOMAIN` set to?

Comment: There's no problem with that line. Best guess: it's the one before it. Which means we should find out what `ETHEME_DOMAIN` is.

Comment: If the code on the specific line looks good, then the syntax error is normally caused by a knock on from somewhere previously.  We need to see more of the code.

Comment: The entire code block you posted seems good, so the issue is most likely above. Mind posting the entire file ?

Comment: Your edit doesn't help, syntax validation stops at the first error, so you need to post the code "before" the implied line.

Comment: Is the missing closing brace in the supplied code, on the 'if' statement, an edit error? if so, then look for an error in the code before the one you indicate as there is nothing obviously incorrect. Mismatched braces can cause this sort of confusion.

Comment: Yeah, it was an edit error in the post - sorry about that. Fixed it. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out what was wrong, but I just ended up backing up from a previous PHP file and everything was fine. Looks like I'll be more careful about how I edit the PHP code in the future.